# Calculating totals and percentages for each row, in a time boxed window, for a relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics, query-optimization

Ok, so I've got two tables: jobs, and job runs. I'm using Postgres.

I want to look at 2 periods.  7 days ago until now, and 14 days ago to 7 days ago.

For each job, I want a total of the number of runs, and a percentage of successful and unsuccessful runs for each period.  I've cooked up this terrible query:

```sql
WITH results AS (
select
        coalesce(count(case when succeeded = true AND timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_passes,
        coalesce(count(case when succeeded = false AND timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_failures,
        coalesce(count(case when timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_total_runs,
        coalesce(count(case when infrastructure_failure = true AND timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_infrastructure_failures,
        
        coalesce(count(case when succeeded = true AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_passes,
        coalesce(count(case when succeeded = false AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_failures,        
        coalesce(count(case when timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_total_runs,
        coalesce(count(case when infrastructure_failure = true AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_infrastructure_failures
FROM
        prow_job_runs JOIN prow_jobs ON prow_jobs.id = prow_job_runs.prow_job_id WHERE prow_jobs.name = 'promote-release-openshift-machine-os-content-e2e-aws-4.10'
)
SELECT *,
        previous_passes * 100.0 / NULLIF(previous_total_runs, 0) AS previous_pass_percentage,
        previous_failures * 100.0 / NULLIF(previous_total_runs, 0) AS previous_failure_percentage,
        current_passes * 100.0 / NULLIF(current_total_runs, 0) AS current_pass_percentage,
        current_failures * 100.0 / NULLIF(current_total_runs, 0) AS current_failure_percentage       
FROM results;
```

Which gets me the result I want:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------------+-----------------------
previous_passes                  | 591
previous_failures                | 4
previous_total_runs              | 595
previous_infrastructure_failures | 1
current_passes                   | 67
current_failures                 | 0
current_total_runs               | 67
current_infrastructure_failures  | 0
previous_pass_percentage         | 99.3277310924369748
previous_failure_percentage      | 0.67226890756302521008
current_pass_percentage          | 100.0000000000000000
current_failure_percentage       | 0.00000000000000000000
```

Here is the execution plan:

```
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on results  (cost=661.12..661.19 rows=1 width=192)
   ->  Aggregate  (cost=661.12..661.13 rows=1 width=64)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.30..650.89 rows=93 width=10)
               Hash Cond: (prow_job_runs.prow_job_id = prow_jobs.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on prow_job_runs  (cost=0.00..603.60 rows=14460 width=18)
               ->  Hash  (cost=8.29..8.29 rows=1 width=8)
                     ->  Index Scan using prow_jobs_name_key on prow_jobs  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=8)
                           Index Cond: (name = 'promote-release-openshift-machine-os-content-e2e-aws-4.10'::text)
(8 rows)
```

But it's only for a single job, how do I do get results for each job without doing a for loop in code?

I also think my query is really slow, it's > 8ms for just one job run.

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide the query `execution plan`.
but you have to make sure you have necessary indices and also maybe you limit your number of rows in join it will be helpful:

```
WITH results AS (
        select prow_jobs.name,
                coalesce(count(case when succeeded = true AND timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_passes,
                coalesce(count(case when succeeded = false AND timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_failures,
                coalesce(count(case when timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_total_runs,
                coalesce(count(case when infrastructure_failure = true AND timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' AND NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as previous_infrastructure_failures,
                coalesce(count(case when succeeded = true AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_passes,
                coalesce(count(case when succeeded = false AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_failures,        
                coalesce(count(case when timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_total_runs,
                coalesce(count(case when infrastructure_failure = true AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY' then 1 end), 0) as current_infrastructure_failures
        FROM prow_job_runs 
        JOIN prow_jobs 
                ON prow_jobs.id = prow_job_runs.prow_job_id                 
                and timestamp BETWEEN NOW() and now() - INTERVAL '14 DAY' 
        group by prow_jobs.name
)
SELECT *,
        previous_passes * 100.0 / NULLIF(previous_total_runs, 0) AS previous_pass_percentage,
        previous_failures * 100.0 / NULLIF(previous_total_runs, 0) AS previous_failure_percentage,
        current_passes * 100.0 / NULLIF(current_total_runs, 0) AS current_pass_percentage,
        current_failures * 100.0 / NULLIF(current_total_runs, 0) AS current_failure_percentage       
FROM results;
```

and seems like you don't have any index on prow_job_runs table, add an index on that table with columns (id,succeeded,infrastructure_failure,timestamp, prow_job_id)

Comment: Thanks, limiting the join is a great idea.  Is there any way to get this for all rows in the job table, or do I need to do a for loop in the client for each job?

Comment: Also I added the execution plan to the original post

Comment: @stbenjam the query in my answer should do the trick, no loop is needed , aslo can you provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` this ?

Comment: It's only doing it for 1 job:  `and prow_jobs.name = 'promote-release-openshift-machine-os-content-e2e-aws-4.10'`

Comment: @stbenjam becasue you limited it to 1 job , remove `and prow_jobs.name = '...'` line and group by jobname , see updated answer

Comment: Amazing, thank you!!